# How to use CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to set --gpus argument of docker run cmd?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, gpu

The [docker run cmd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) docs show an example of how to specify several (but not all) gpus:

```
docker run -it --rm --gpus '"device=0,2"' nvidia-smi
```

I'd like to set the --gpus to use those indicated by the environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES.

I tried the obvious

```
docker run --rm -it --env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES --gpus '"device=$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"' some_repo:some_tag /bin/bash
```

But this gives the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: device error: $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: unknown device: unknown.
```

Note: currently `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1`

I saw a [github issue about this](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/11010?force_isolation=true), but the solution is a bit messy and didn't work for me.

What is a good way to use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to set `--gpus` argument of `docker run` cmd?

Answer (score 2):

The single quotes in `'"device=$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"'` prevent the expansion of the variable. Try without the single quotes.

```
docker run --rm -it \
  --env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES \
  --gpus device=$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES some_repo:some_tag /bin/bash
```

Comment: @user3731622 did this answer solve your problem?